# Dealing with large amount of form fields in React using Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

recently i played with React-hooks to handle large amount of form field which is iterated from array. my goal is to prevent unnecessary re-render on field component that not changed. I achieve it with this code, but still some questions hanging:

```
import React, { useState, useCallback, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function Multipleform() {
  // use useRef to prevent re-render of component due to state change
  // create empty array with length of n
  let data = useRef([...Array(5000).fill('')]);
  let [reloader, setReloader] = useState(0);

  // wrap handler with useCallback to keep its reference
  // so React.memo will not consider it change overtime
  const handler = useCallback((e, i) => {
    // change state to rerender component, so i can see changes in ref
    setReloader((val) => val + 1);
    data.current[i] = e.target.value;
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Form</h1>
      {/* to log current state */}
      <button onClick={() => console.log(data.current)}>log state</button>
      {/* just print string of array to see state (ref value) changes  */}
      <p>{data.current.filter(Boolean).toString()}</p>
      {data.current.map((x, i) => {
        return (
          <MemoizedField data={x} key={i} handler={(e) => handler(e, i)} />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

const MemoizedField = React.memo(
  ({ data, handler }) => {
    useCountRenders();
    return <input value={data} onChange={handler} />;
  },
  // 1. why should i put this, if React.memo itself will prevent re-render if no props changed?
  (prev, next) => prev.data === next.data
);

// custom hooks to see re renders count of certain component
export const useCountRenders = () => {
  const renders = useRef(0);
  useEffect(() => console.log('renders: ', renders.current++));
};
```

1. same in the comment, why should i put prev and next comparison, if React.memo itself will prevent re-render if no props changed?
2. Do i have misconception from my understanding of hooks usage from above?
3. Does the code good enough or can i improved that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think rest all looks fine.
There seems to be a problem here

```
 <MemoizedField data={x} key={i} handler={(e) => handler(e, i)} />
```

You should use the handler directly otherwise useCallback won't have any effect. On each render the function would be created.

```
<MemoizedField data={x} key={i} handler={handler} />
```

Comment: Also why not put the value of inputs in state if you're anyway using it as a controlled component but with refs

Comment: i've tried that. but the state back to its initial value each re renders. and you right, i changed the handler to the MemoizeField and i can remove the state comparison :D

Comment: you might be using useState in a wrong way then.
Pls show an example on how you're using setState function

Comment: here is my implementation with useState, actually i missed out putting dependencies to useCallback, its work now, but you can see tho console to see re renders happened. https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-spence-nhtnt?file=/src/App.js .

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/falling-rgb-39xjs?file=/src/App.js
Here you are w/o the memo. I've added dependencies in useCount Otherwise it re-renders just cos of ref.current++.

Comment: Updated with Memo!

Comment: Wow cool implementation with only useState man. btw can you translate the aim of  `state.map((x, index) => (index === i ? value ?? "" : x))` i know it edit specific value changed, but i dont know the use of `??`. i think its sufficient to only use `index === i ? value : x`

Comment: ?? is a new operator added in js. You can ignore that for sure.